# Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage: 142590947360768' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY'

Tags: sql, sql-server, tempdb

```
Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  142590947360768' 
in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY'.....
```

This error message happened 3 days ago. How can I track down what/where/when/how/who caused it? I am very new to this any advice or direction would be much appreciated. 
I tried

```
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.allocation_units WHERE allocation_unit_id = '142590947360768';
```

But it's no showing anything.

Comment: I think you will need to allocate more space to PRIMARY in tempdb, or set it to autogrow.

Comment: If that session / object has gone away since three days ago (likely), I don't think you're going to find anything about it, though the default trace may at least still have any growth events that led up to it, and it _may_ contain other information about objects created around the same time. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186

Comment: To capture better info about file growth events in the future, by setting up a proactive Extended Events session, see this series: [Part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/03/extended-events/removing-default-trace-1) | [Part 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/04/extended-events/removing-default-trace-2) | [Part 3](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/04/extended-events/removing-default-trace-3)